# Parsing Data From a File on the server

Tags: c#

I have an application on a server and I want it to send a file that can be parsed for the data I am looking for with as little human error as possible.

I am not sure what tags to attach to this it is being coded in C# though.

I was thinking an excel spreadsheet but it can be changed to easily from what I'm told.

What is a vaible way to recieve data to be parsed that can have any format?
Or
What is a way to enter data to get to the network without setting up a program?

Edit:
The server is on a diffrent network than the user wich they cannot directly access.

Comment: Can you please be more specific and clear to your problem ?

Comment: Is your question how to parse the data, how to receive the file, or how to get started.  I'm not sure what you looking for please add details like what the environment how you plan on communicating with the server or if you are look on advice on how one would do that.

Comment: @Rerun: I'm asking at a higher way than how to code it. More of what are ways to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InfoPath is made for user form data like that.

Excel is another option, but you're right - its difficult to validate user input.

Google Spreadsheet's Forms feature is a nice alternative but getting the data from the spreadsheet afterward could be a pain.

Comment: Would that require MS office on the server?

Comment: None of those options would require Office on the server.  InfoPath can submit to xml or SQL.  Excel can be read with JetDb.  GoogleSpreadsheet would require the GData API

Comment: The people entering the data are on a diffrent network than the application. It is not directly connected to the internet.

Comment: How do you plan to pass data back and forth then?  The clients have to be able to access the server via some sort of network.